# R way to select unique columns from column name?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

my issue is I have a big database of 283 columns, some of which have the same name (for example, "uncultured"). 
Is there a way to select columns avoiding those with repeated names? Those (bacteria) normally have a very small abundance, so I don't really care for their contribution, I'd just like to take the columns with unique names.

My database is something like

```
    Samples  col1  col2  col3  col4 col2 col1.... 
S1
S2
S3
...
```

and I'd like to select every column but the second `col2` and `col1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
df[, !duplicated(colnames(df))]
```

Comment: or just: `df[!duplicated(colnames(df))]`

Comment: Thank you both! It works, I was clueless without knowing about "duplicated"

Answer (score 3):

Like this you will automatically select the first column with a unique name:

```r
df[unique(colnames(df))]
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4 S1 S2 S3
#> 1    1    2    3    4  7  8  9
#> 2    1    2    3    4  7  8  9
#> 3    1    2    3    4  7  8  9
#> 4    1    2    3    4  7  8  9
#> 5    1    2    3    4  7  8  9
```

## Reproducible example

`df` is defined as:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(1:9, 5), ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col2", "col1", "S1", "S2", "S3")
df
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4 col2 col1 S1 S2 S3
#> 1    1    2    3    4    5    6  7  8  9
#> 2    1    2    3    4    5    6  7  8  9
#> 3    1    2    3    4    5    6  7  8  9
#> 4    1    2    3    4    5    6  7  8  9
#> 5    1    2    3    4    5    6  7  8  9
```

Comment: Or `df[,unique(colnames(df))]`.

Comment: Since my columns ar not as ordinated as in my simple example, unique for the first col was not the solution I was looking for, but I'll keep it in mind for the next occasion, I didn't know at all how to manipulate colnames. Thank you!